# Changing the date format to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I've got a date column that contains dates in mixed format. For example:

> A
>   
> 21.03.1990
>   
> 03/21/1990

So, basically there are two different formats in one column: `dd.mm.yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy`. I'm trying to write a VBA script to change format of all dates in the column to be `yyyy-mm-dd`. That's what I've got so far:

```
Sub changeFormat()

Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim cell As Range, i As Long
Dim LValue As String

i = 1

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rLastCell = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & rLastCell.Row)
        LValue = Format(cell.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        .Range("B" & i).Value = LValue
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub
```

I know that it's not elegant piece of code, but I'm beginner with VBA so please forgive me. 
The problem with that code is that it just rewrite unchanged A column into column B, when I change argument in Format function from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `dd/mm/yyyy` it works, but only for dates in format `mm/dd/yyyy`, and leaves `dd.mm.yyyy` untouched. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: As far as I know "21.03.1990" is not a date format, it's just text that is entered that way. Can you check the cell format and confirm? If it's text, then changing the format of the date will do nothing to the contents.

Comment: IMHO, VBA may more trouble than it's worth. This task can be accomplished with a fairly simple Excel formula.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATED: NEW ANSWER**

Here is a solution that will do the job! The sub routine includes a function that does the replacement (the function itself is really useful!). Run the sub and all occurances in column A will be fixed.

```
Sub FixDates()

Dim cell As range
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    If InStr(cell.Value, ".") <> 0 Then
        cell.Value = RegexReplace(cell.Value, _
        "(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})", "$3-$2-$1")
    End If
    If InStr(cell.Value, "/") <> 0 Then
        cell.Value = RegexReplace(cell.Value, _
        "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})", "$3-$1-$2")
    End If
    cell.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-d;@"
Next

End Sub
```

Place this function in the same module:

```
Function RegexReplace(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal replace_what As String, _
                      ByVal replace_with As String) As String

Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.pattern = replace_what
RE.Global = True
RegexReplace = RE.Replace(text, replace_with)

End Function
```

**How it works**: I have a nifty RegexReplace function that allows you to do replace using regular expressions. The sub mearly loops through your A column and does a regex replace for those 2 cases you mentioned. The reason I use an Instr() first is to determain if it needs the replacement, and which kind. You could technically skip this but doing replace on cells that don't need it is really costly. At the end I format the cell to your custom date format regardless of what's inside for safe measure.

In case you aren't familiar with Regex (for ref: http://www.regular-expressions.info/), the expression I am using is:

- Each item in () are capture groups - aka, the stuff you want to mess with
- \d stands for a number [0-9].
- {2} means 2 of, and {4} mean 4 of. I have been explicit here for safety.
- The \ before the . in the first replace is needed since "." has special meaning.
- In VBA regex, you refer to capture groups by using $ + no. of group. This is how I flip the order of the 3 items.

Comment: Try IF ISTEXT(cell) AND INSTR(1,cell.text,".") THEN cell.value = DATESERIAL(RIGHT(cell.TEXT,4), MID(cell.TEXT,4,2), LEFT(cell.TEXT,2)).  This should convert to a real Excel data format, after which you can apply your cell formatting.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need VBA for this. This one-liner worksheet formula will do the trick:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",A1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",A1)),"invalid format",
    DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2))),
    DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)))
```

This assumes the day and month are always given as two-digit numbers (e.g. always 03 and never just 3) and the year has four digits (i.e. "restricted" to years 1000-9999). But if this is not the case for you, then the formula can easily be adjusted to suit your purpose.

Comment: +1 Very nice! I have a tendency to just code something in VBA (mainly becuase I have a bad habit of mistyping long formulas) but this is the most effecient way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

See if this does what you want. You may have to tailor it a bit for your own application.

Hope this helps!

```
Sub convertDates()
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sDest As String
    Dim sYear, sMonth, sDay, aDate

    'Range where the dates are stored, excluding header
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A11")

    'Column name of destination
    sDest = "B"

    'You could also use the following, and just select the range.
    'Set rRng = Application.selection

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        sYear = 99999

        If InStr(rCell.Value, ".") > 0 Then
            aDate = Split(rCell.Value, ".")
            If UBound(aDate) = 2 Then
                sDay = aDate(0)
                sMonth = aDate(1)
                sYear = aDate(2)
            End If
        ElseIf InStr(rCell.Value, "/") > 0 Then
            aDate = Split(rCell.Value, "/")
            If UBound(aDate) = 2 Then
                sDay = aDate(1)
                sMonth = aDate(0)
                sYear = aDate(2)
            End If
        End If

        With rCell.Range(sDest & "1")
            If sYear <> 99999 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                .Value = "'" & Format(CDate(sMonth & "/" & sDay & "/" & sYear), "YYYY-MM-DD")
                'If it can't convert the date, just put the original value in the dest
                'cell. You can tailor this to your own preference.
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then .Value = rCell.Value
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                .Value = rCell.Value
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jean-François Corbett has a formula solution that works but that might be shortened by more than half by foregoing the error message (on the basis that `#VALUE!` is as informative) and another IF, both DATEs, applying IFERROR rather than ISERROR, and SUBSTITUTE in place of one LEFT, MID, RIGHT set:

```
=IFERROR(1*(MID(A1,4,3)&LEFT(A1,3)&RIGHT(A1,4)),1*SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"))
```

This applies the interpretation mentioned by @Issun in the comment to the OP and assumes the output will be to cells formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`.

May be written with a subroutine like so:

```
Sub Macro1()
Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=IFERROR(1*(MID(A1,4,3)&LEFT(A1,3)&RIGHT(A1,4)),1*SUBSTITUTE(A1,""."",""/""))"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to this:

```
     Sub ChangeFormat1()

              Dim ws as Worksheet
                 Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
                 LR = ws.cells(rows.count,1).End(Xlup).Row

                 with ws
                        For I = 1 to LR
                          .cells(I,2).value = .cells(I,1).value
                        Next
                 End with

                 ws.range("B1:B" & LR).numberformat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
      End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & "-" & Year(Date)