# Excel : Date format issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have few cells where I fill date in those using 'FormatDatetime' function,

code:

```
Range("AX1") = FormatDateTime((Docx.getAttribute("r1ed")))
Range("AX2") = FormatDateTime((Docx.getAttribute("r2ed")))
Range("AX3") = FormatDateTime((Docx.getAttribute("r3ed")))
Range("AX4") = FormatDateTime((Docx.getAttribute("r4ed")))
```

If date is separated by "." all the cells would show like "12.1.2013",but if I change my system date format separated by "-","AX4" shows date as still "12.1.2013".but other shows correctly.

I need to have fix for this,since I use these dates' for calculation later in VBA.

Please suggest some answers.

Comment: Would something like the solution at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106238/vba-excel-changing-date-format` work for you?

Comment: @chuff -> you can put links right in your comment by surrounding them with `()`. You can create an easier name by placing `[link name]`. SO calls it mini-markup. So it would be `[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106238...)`

Comment: @chuff:I used the function, but when I tried to substract cells like "AX1-AX7" i get "#VALUE!", but both have same format like '2013-20-02'.What`s wrong here???

Comment: Check whether the dates are actually text strings. If so, you can convert them to date values using the DATEVALUE("text_date") function.

Comment: One thing I dont understand,how come only one cell is showing format in a different format??

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that `FormatDateTime()` returns a string, change it to `DateValue()` instead. If the return from `Docx.getAttribute()` contains dots you'll need to replace them with slashes first.

So;

```
'[AX1] is the same as Range("AX1")
[AX1] = DateValue(Docx.getAttribute("r1ed"))
[AX2] = DateValue(Docx.getAttribute("r2ed"))
[AX3] = DateValue(Docx.getAttribute("r3ed"))
[AX4] = DateValue(Docx.getAttribute("r4ed"))
```

Or, if there are dots;

```
[AX1] = DateValue(Replace(Docx.getAttribute("r1ed"), ".", "/"))
[AX2] = DateValue(Replace(Docx.getAttribute("r2ed"), ".", "/"))
[AX3] = DateValue(Replace(Docx.getAttribute("r3ed"), ".", "/"))
[AX4] = DateValue(Replace(Docx.getAttribute("r4ed"), ".", "/"))
```

If this doesn't solve the issue, can you please post more info about what `Docx.getAttribute()` is returning please.

---

Edit: Also, knowing the format you need the cells to contain would be helpful - I'm assuming proper dates will be acceptable - You might need a string with a date in a certain format. If that's the case you could wrap the above with something like;

```
[AX1] = Format(DateValue(Docx.getAttribute("r1ed")), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

It might be that `FormatDateTime()` is betraying you, `Format()` might be more flexible