# Excel not recognizing year when changing to date format with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble changing to date format. I have cells containing different dates but not all of them are formatted as date. One of them is "yy-mm-dd", for example "13-04-08", but it is formatted as General. 
I'm using this code:

```
xCell = Format(xCell, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Problem is that excel cannot tell if "13" or "08" is the "yyyy" so it doesn't change anything. How do I solve this? Do I need to tell excel which numbers are year before it changes the date, and how do I do that? Can it be included in the Format method?

**EDIT:**
I think I need to explain the whole thing as the problem seems to lay somewhere else.
The cells containing the dates look like this from start, being formatted as General:

```
13-05-06 A
13-05-21 A
...
```

I remove the unwanted 'A' with this code:

```
Sub rensa()

Dim Found As Range

For Each xCell In Range("D2:D999")
    If IsEmpty(xCell.Value) Then Exit For
        Set Found = xCell.Find(What:="A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If Found Is Nothing Then
            Else
                xCell.Value = Left(xCell.Value, Len(xCell.Value) - 1)
            End If
    Next xCell

End Sub
```

I have tried these codes to set the cell format to date:

```
Range("D2:D999").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
Range("D2:D999").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

I have also tried to implement them in the For loop like this:

```
Sub rensa()

Dim Found As Range

For Each xCell In Range("D2:D999")
If IsEmpty(xCell.Value) Then Exit For
    Set Found = xCell.Find(What:="A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Found Is Nothing Then
            xCell.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        Else
            xCell.Value = Left(xCell.Value, Len(xCell.Value) - 1)
            xCell.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
        End If
Next xCell

End Sub
```

But that didn't work as I wanted either. Everything makes the result look like this, still formatted as General:

```
13-05-06
13-05-21
...
```

So the A is gone, but nothing else changes.

Comment: You need to use Regular Expression to tell Excel which is day number and year number.

Here is relative answer to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7106594/516245

Comment: The real description of the problem seems to be that the cell data is not a date, but a string.

Comment: @iDevelop You are right, the cell data is not a date from the beginning. Maybe the title should say "...when changing TO date format"?

Comment: iDevlop is correct. simply put a `date` variable wherein you can pass the cell value. then return that variable as the cell value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just added something in your code. See below lines with comments

```
Sub rensa()

Dim Found As Range
Dim xcell As Range
Dim date_val As Date

For Each xcell In Range("D1:D999")
    If IsEmpty(xcell.Value) Then Exit For
        Set Found = xcell.Find(What:="A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If Found Is Nothing Then
            Else
                xcell.Value = Left(xcell.Value, Len(xcell.Value) - 1)
                date_val = xcell.Value 'asign the value to date variable carrier
                xcell.Value = date_val 'return it to the cell
            End If
Next xcell

Range("D1:D999").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" 'do the formatting

End Sub
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple solution is to parse your data using `Mid, Left, Right functions`. However, it's not such efficient one would expect but possibly would be helpful. So, the code could be as follows:

```
xCell = "13-04-08"
xCell = Format(DateSerial(Left(xCell,2),mid(xCell,4,2),Right(xCell,2)),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

as a result you get `2013-04-08`.

**Edit** To set appropriate cell formatting try one of the following:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

or

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

Where `Range("A1")` is reference to your cell/range in Excel sheet.

Comment: if you see incorrect output in cell then you need to change `cell formatting` to something like `long date`. In VBA there is `2013-04-08` for sure. Alternatively you could try to add `'` before `format function` in this way: `xCell = "'" & Format(...`

Comment: I updated my question a bit, I have tried this didn't work or something else is wrong.