# convert MMM DD, YYYY HH:MM:SS am in excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet which contains the loading times for my website. I want to find the peak hour for my website.

However the dates are stored in the following format:

```
Jun 02, 2014 01:13:08 am
MMM DD, YYYY HH:MM:SS am / pm
```

How can I convert this in to date that excel will understand?

Comment: You could change the cell formatting.

Comment: I've tried that, excel still does not see it as a date

Comment: Do you have an English language version of Excel?  If so, there may be a non-printing character in the string -- probably a NBSP (ASCII 160).  Try doing a Find/Replace to remove those characters.

Comment: As a test, can you tell me what you get as a result of the formula: =A1+0 when A1 contains a slight modification to your string example: 02 Jun, 2014 01:13:08 am (be sure to format the cell as text before entering this string)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587037/excel-vba-extract-the-correct-dates-from-badly-formatted-dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert your "pseudo-dates" into real dates, select them and run:

```
Sub ConvertDates()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = CDate(r.Text)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Errors if there is data in-between that does not match the format (Like "N/A"), but works well...

Comment: Not working on OS X, depending on regional settings.... See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738609/vba-cdate-not-working-on-mac-excel-201114-7-1)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - via change in windows regional settings.

[image: before/after]

Start with `.CVS` file with date in `MMM DD", "YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM`

In windows 10, Open:

Control Panel > Clock and Region > Region

In long date, enter `MMM dd,yyyy` > OK.

[image: Windows regional settings]

Reboot, then open the excel file, the text is recognized as date.

Comment: File need to be in .csv format

Answer (score -2):

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(MID(A1,4,FIND(",",A1)-4)&"/"&MONTH(LEFT(A1,3)&1)&"/"&MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,4))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8)),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply