# VBA cDate not working on Mac excel 2011(14.7.1)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to convert a date into long using VBA script.
Below is the code snippet

```
Sub test()
    Dim str as string
    Dim d as variant
    str="1/1/2016"
    d=cdate(str)
end sub
```

The above snippet runs fine on windows but is giving me type mismatch error on MAC.
Is there any turnaround to convert a valid string in a date.

Comment: what is your Mac's region/language settings?

Comment: Also, what line are you getting the error on and what is the exact error message?

Comment: It is on US settings

Comment: Hey Dai on Cdate I am getting type mismatch error

Comment: I'm suspecting Variant datatype failure, have you tried `Dim d as Date` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well but it still gives me the same error. Also I have noticed that none of the date functions are working on MAC excel

Comment: Nop, it does not work

Comment: Does this fix help [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/vba-for-excel-2011-no-longer-handling-dates-since/3d04e3b6-3cbc-4a36-89e8-323de4f1c7d1)

Comment: @Han it didn't fix the errors

Comment: Tried to get that same error on my Mac today, but no luck. This makes me suspect that it is very much certain setting combination specific problem/bug, something I can't figure where the problem could be. Tried using US settings and such but it works perfectly fine on my Mac... You could try and create a dummy user account and check if there is something in your user profile that makes it act weird but other than that I'm all out of ideas..

Comment: @Han thanks han for all your help, I'll try it for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your regional settings are the root cause.

Can you try modify them?

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleICUDateFormatStrings -dict 1 dd/MM/yyyy
```

Comment: This should be done in MacOS Terminal, related to system settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your code did work on my local OS X machine with Excel. I have different region settings, though. I would suggest try using the international date format ("YYYY-mm-dd").

```
Sub Main
    Dim str as String
    Dim d as Variant
    str = "2016-01-01"
    d = CDate(str)
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could try "Jan/1/2016".

---

P.S.: You can see your date & time settings in OS X under System Preferences -> Language & Region -> Advanced -> Dates:

[image: OS X language & region date settings]

Comment: Please refer to the link provided by Hank in comments above

Comment: The problem is if CDate is used to covnert from a weird format, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990811/convert-mmm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-am-in-excel)....

Answer (score 1):

Many different answer, so I may as well throw this way of doing it it into the ring,

```
Sub test()
    Dim str As String
    Dim d As Variant
    str = "1/1/2016"
    d = CDate(Format(str, "dd/MM/yyyy"))
    Debug.Print d
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try removing the "/" before converting? I do not have a Mac to test:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim str As String
    Dim d As Long 'should be Date, but your question states Long
    str = "1/1/2016"
    d = CDate(Replace(str, "/", ""))
    Debug.Print d
End Sub
```

Also, have you tried checking for missing references? [Date for VBA not working in Excel 2011?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476793/date-for-vba-not-working-in-excel-2011)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IsDate() function to check if it is a date before converting. Otherwise use a workaround:

```
Sub test()
    Dim str as string
    Dim d as variant
    str = "1/1/2016"

    If IsDate(str) then
       d = CDate(str)
    Else
       Dim aDateParts() as String
       aDateParts() = Split(str, "/")

       ' DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)
       d = DateSerial(CInt(aDateParts(2)), CInt(aDateParts(0)), CInt(aDateParts(1)))
    End If
end sub
```

Comment: So far the only answer providing a possible workaround, however I'm not sure does `IsDate(str)` prevent the str being validated as a date although assigning `d` might fail. Also if the date string is something funny like "1/32/2017" we get to the else part where bad things start to happen.

Comment: I was going to do this with a left/mid/right for the day month year, your answer is better with the split function.  In my view this could be improved by putting it into a: Function ConDate(InputDate as string) as date

Comment: @HanSoalone This code was more a proof of concept than a working solution, it should be refined if that's an acceptable solution. Tom, thanks, it seems like a good idea! What's the best practice here? Should I upvote your solution?

Comment: @sebifeixler I understood that and it is a good concept, I just wanted to point out the problems this approach might bring. Likely the solution will work ok, if added some error checking etc.

Comment: It is sure a nice workaround but just want to let you guys know one thing, DateSerial is not working on my Mac

Answer (score 0):

I didn't post this originally, because I felt it didn't address the root of the problem, however, if you want a workaround, you can use the below function in a similar way as you would use a `CDate`, by calling `ConDate("12/12/2016")`.

This is is the way I approached the problem:

```
Sub MainTest()
    Dim InputString As String, OutputDate As Date

    InputString = "01/12/2016"
    OutputDate = ConDate(InputString)

    Debug.Print OutputDate, TypeName(OutputDate)
End Sub

Function ConDate(ByRef InputString As String) As Date
    Dim Day As Long, Month As Long, year As Long
    'mmddyyyy format
    Month = CLng(Left(InputString, InStr(1, InputString, "/", vbTextCompare) - 1))
    Day = CLng(Mid(InputString, InStr(1, InputString, "/", vbTextCompare) + 1, InStrRev(InputString, "/", , vbTextCompare) - InStr(1, InputString, "/", vbTextCompare) - 1))
    year = CLng(Right(InputString, 4))
    ConDate = DateSerial(year, Month, Day)
End Function
```

Not wanting to plagerise sebifeixler's answer I kept my original left/mid/right to separate the day/month/year, but I feel it's much neater to use his split function to separate the date by "/".  A combination of the two would be a good workaround.